# HTML List elements - tables in forms

Tags: html, forms, list, html-table

I have 2 forms in tables which I want to include in a list and the bullet must appear only for the first element. Where should I put the `<li>` tag?  Thank you

```
<ul class="ul_arrow">
    <li>
        <form .....>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <t></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <form ...>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <t></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.jsp"><fmt:message key="text.back" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate..

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want by using CSS.
The correct CSS would be something like this:

```
.bulletPrefix {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

With HTML:

```
<span class="bulletPrefix">There will be a bullet prefixing this line</span>
```

In general you should avoid using tables as lists, as you seem to be doing. You should use s for lists. You also seem to be using s for a divider or something. You should use 's for that.

Answer (score 0):

The markup looks odd, but if you just want to have a list with two elements and only the first one be bulleted, simply use a piece of CSS that removes the bullet from the latter. A simple way is to put a `style` attribute into the latter `<li>` tag:

```html
<ul class="ul_arrow">
    <li>
        <form .....>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <t></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <form ...>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="445px">
                <tr>
                    <td> :</td>
                    <t></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none"><a href="index.jsp"><fmt:message key="text.back" /></a></li>
</ul>
```